# Setting Git for a team of 3 people?

Tags: git, version-control, gitosis

**The post aims to summarize all pieces of information to set up a closed repository for 3 people in a competition.** Please, feel free to add a problem to the list which I have not noted. Please, add each answer to each question as a separate answer.

1. **Situation A:** Drafts and files can exchange between 3 people. The
   writer can only push files to the
   repository.
2. **Situation B:** Similarly as above, but all team mates can push files to the repository.

**The general problems about Situation A**

- How can you set up remote branches for people A, B and C, so that team members can see files which their team members want to share?
- How can you set up the person A as a dictator, who can only push changes to the sacred repository?

**Initial Problems about Situation A**

1. *[How can you set up a Git repository, where people A, B and C can pull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550913/setting-git-for-a-team-of-3-people/552189#552189)* I assume Git is already successfully installed to the repository
2. *How can you allow the writer only push?*

**Advanced Problems about both Situations**

- [How can you set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550913/setting-git-for-a-team-of-3-people/627470#627470) up [Gitosis](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way) to your server by first setting up Python Setup-tools, when you do not have sudo access?
- [How can you report bugs efficiently to your team mates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550913/setting-git-for-a-team-of-3-people/901838#901838)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Situation A**

It sounds like you want to set up a [integration manager workflow](http://www.whygitisbetterthanx.com/#any-workflow).  In this scenario, person A creates an initial repository which is the sacred repository.  Each person, A, B and C, clones that repository for their personal work.  When person B or C has something they want A to include in the repository for sharing, they commit it to their local repository, and ask A to pull from their repository (a *pull request*); person A sets up *remote*s for person B's and person C's repositories and then can `git pull personB` or `git pull personB` to merge in the changes.  Person A then `git push`s the merged changes into the sacred repository.

You can set up the cloning and pushing over a variety of transports.  The easiest is to use the git protocol over ssh. e.g.,

1. Person A makes the sacred repository: see 'Creating a remote repository' at this [page from 37signals](https://37s.backpackit.com/pub/1465067).  Let's say it is in `/local/git/project.git` on `sharedhost`.  You can leave out the `--shared=group` since you want it to be an integration repository.  (Write access here is protected using Unix file permissions.)
2. Person A, B and C, in their home directories, clone that repository.

   ```
   cd ~/src
   git clone ssh://sharedhost//local/git/project.git
   cd project # edit files in here.
   git commit
   ```
3. Person A sets up remotes for B and C's repositories.

   ```
   git remote add personB ssh://sharedhost/~b/src/project
   git remote add personC ssh://sharedhost/~c/src/project
   ```
4. Now person A can `git pull personB` to fetch B's changes.  When A is happy, he will `git push` to push the newly merged changes to the shared repo and B and C can `git pull` to fetch them.

If setting up the repositories sounds a bit complex, you may want to pay a provider such as [GitHub](http://github.com/plans/) to handle all the hosting of shared git repositories for you.  They also have support where they can help you out with problems.
For me, I found that the trickiest part is understanding the flow of commits.  Once you get that, things start to make more sense.  This [discussion at gitready.com](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/21/pushing-and-pulling.html) might help clarify things for you.  There is also a [screencast](http://www.gitcasts.com/posts/distributed-workflow) that covers similar material.

Comment: We also use the integration manager workflow. It is beautifully productive and secure, and scales nicely to any team size. 

In our experience, *setting this up was easy in terms of technicals, but the mental change was not that trivial for developers*. That's why we made a short tutorial video for our own team, that we later published on YouTube: [What is the Integrator Workflow?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67zQHNO2gaQ)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How can you set up a Git repository, where people A, B and C
>      can pull?

You need to use ssh -protocol (ssh username@ipAddress), and provide ssh access to 3 people, by providing an account for them on the machine that hosts the repository ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552121/setting-a-password-for-git-cloning/552148#552148)).

I recommend to provide SSH keys for your team members.
Please, see [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591766/can-i-use-ssh-keys-in-something-other-than-putty-on-mac).
This allows them to clone by running, for instance:

```
git clone user@machine:/path/to/repo.git
```

---

**A developed problem**

> How can you provide an account for 3
>   people?

If your files must be private, I recommend you to have an account at Github which costs you a few bucks. You can also set up a repo at your own server by Gitosis.

If your files can be open, I recommend you to use Github, since it is free for that purpose.

---

**A more developed problem**

> How can you add an user to your Git
>   repository?

You can add an user to your team by running the following code at your Git branch

```
git add remote UserName ssh://ADDressToTheRepo
```

**Example of the command**

```
git add remote schacon git://github.com/schacon/ticgit.git
```

---

**A more-more developed problem**

> How can you add your friend's branch
>   to your Git?

Please, see my answer at [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904353/unable-to-understand-git-branch-merge-and-rebase/907799#907799).

Comment: it is definitely possible to use setuptools without sudo access, you have to add some options (why setuptools requires those is another story...). The options are: python setup.py --single-version-externally-managed --record=/dev/null --prefix=myprefix

Answer (score 0):

One suggested me the use of Gitosis, which raised a [new problem](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way):
***How can you set up Gitosis to your server by first setting up Python-setuptools, when you do not have sudo access?***

**Solution to install Gitosis**: Please, see [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622744/unable-to-install-python-without-sudo-access/622810#622810) to install the newest Python. Note that your system probably has an old Python. You cannot update the system-Python without updating the whole OS. For example, you cannot update Mac Leopard's Python because the system depends on it.

Now, you can start to install python-setuptools. Please, see [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624671/unable-to-install-python-setuptools-from-source) to install them.

Answer (score 0):

> How can you report bugs efficiently to
>   your team mates?

I had a problem in reporting bugs and feature requests to my team mates.

The software [TicGit](http://github.com/schacon/ticgit/tree/master) solves the problem for me. It is a ticket system for Git, which you can install simply by setting it up as a separate branch to your project.