# Setting a password for Git cloning?

Tags: git, git-clone

I want to put a password to my repository so that the password is asked, when cloning from my repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To restrict access to repository cloning, you need to use the ssh://... protocol, and provide ssh access to only those users you want to have access.

What you probably should do is look up the various "git workflow" questions and answers - they describe the means by which various team members pull/push from/to each other.  There are many ways to do this.

Comment: How can I provide ssh access to those users which I want to have access?

Comment: You create an account for them on the machine that hosts the repo, so they can clone by running something like:  git clone user@machine:/path/to/repo.git

Answer (score 3):

I recomend gitosis to manage private repositories.

[Here](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way) you have a nice Tutorial