# Can I use SSH keys in something other than PuTTy (on Mac)?

Tags: ssh-keys

Bluehost only recommends PuTTy. However, is it possible to use ssh keys without any extra, visible programs in Mac?

I would like to have a connection to my server to be a breeze, so that I can control my server in Terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course!  On Unix and OS X, the `ssh-keygen` command will generate public and private keys for SSH public-key authentication.  The usual way to invoke this command (on the client) is:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

This command will ask you where to place your private key; the default place is `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, and the public key will be placed in the file of the same name with a `.pub` extension added (for example: `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`).  The command also asks you to create a password ("passphrase") for the private key; you can leave it blank for no password as I do, but I don't recommend this practice.

Once you have your public and private keys on the client computer, you need to make your server recognize that public key.  If you have shell access to the server, you can upload the public key file with `scp`, then use `ssh` to run the following command on the server:

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

If your hosting company doesn't give you shell access (though Bluehost does), or this procedure doesn't work, it will likely give you a web interface to the same functionality.

Once your server is set up to recognize your public key, it will allow you access without a password when `ssh` on the client tries to use your private key for authentication.  You may still have to enter your private key's password, but typically you only need to do this once for each client login session.

Comment: Are you suggesting to create a *passwordless* private key?

Comment: Yes, that's a bad practice, but it's what I normally use.  I will edit my answer to address that concern.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, I do this all the time. Just follow [these](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/66) directions to generate an SSH key and copy it to your server. The instructions should work on both Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

[SSHKeychain](http://www.sshkeychain.org/) is pretty much ideal for this. It lives unobtrusively on the menu bar and integrates seamlessly with OS X's Keychain and SSH implementations.

You will need to use `ssh-keygen` as described in other answers, but once you've done that you can use SSHKeychain to avoid having to type your private key passphrase all the time.

Comment: I can't believe I never heard of SSHKeychain.  When I get home I will try it!

Comment: "Leopard has ssh-agent built" -http://www.sshkeychain.org/pipermail/users/2008-September/000238.html  I noted that when my installation of SSHKeychain failed similarly as in the link. Do I need the software for Leopard?

Comment: @Masi: I don't know, I'm using Tiger (10.4). SSHKeychain hasn't been updated for a while, so it may indeed be obsolete now.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSH should be available to you on OS X; open a terminal and check out "man ssh".  SSH keys get stored (in a format different from PuTTY) in ~/.ssh.  Having a config in ~/.ssh/config can make your life easier, too; you'll be able to say "Use this $SHORTNAME for this $HOST using this $KEY" and similar.

Answer (score 1):

At the terminal prompt do

```
$ apropos ssh
```

You should get a list of all the programs Mac OS X comes with related to ssh.

Using the `ssh*` tools, your ssh keys will be stored under `~/.ssh`. PuTTY is nice, but compared to the standard OpenSSH tools, it's really only useful on Windows systems.

Answer (score 1):

Sure can! First run:

```
ssh-keygen
```

And go through the steps. It is a good idea to give it a password and such. Then you can:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

and copy-paste the result into the bluehost public key textarea.

Comment: I have now my key pair at Bluehost. I connected to my server by "ssh username@ipAddress" and it still asks my password. How can I see the difference?

Comment: Have you gotten bluehost to turn on SSH? I think they need a scan of some photo ID or something...

Comment: @Masi: Bluehost also makes you "authorize" the key in the control panel in addition to just giving them the public key... If you have already done that then I have nothing else to offer. I'm on a Mac sshing to my Bluehost machine right now, and all I had to do was give them the key and authorize it.

Comment: @Mike: Thank you! It seems to work. It does not ask my passphrase. Is it a security problem?