# Unable to install Python without sudo access

Tags: python, installation, sudo

I extracted, configured and used make for the installation package in my server.

However, I could not use *make install*. I get the error

```
[~/wepapps/python/Python-2.6.1]# make install
/usr/bin/install -c python /usr/local/bin/python2.6
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/bin/python2.6': Permission denied
make: *** [altbininstall] Error 1
```

I run the folder with

```
chmod +x Python-2.6.1
```

I get still the same error.

How can I run *make install* without sudo access?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

> How can I install to a path under my home directory?

```
mkdir /home/masi/.local

cd Python-2.6.1
make clean
./configure --prefix=/home/masi/.local
make
make install
```

Then run using:

```
/home/masi/.local/bin/python
```

Similarly if you have scripts (eg. CGI) that require your own user version of Python you have to tell them explicitly:

```
#!/home/masi/.local/bin/python
```

instead of using the default system Python which “#!/usr/bin/env python” will choose.

You can alter your PATH setting to make just typing “python” from the console run that version, but it won't help for web apps being run under a different user.

If you compile something that links to Python (eg. mod_wsgi) you have to tell it where to find your Python or it will use the system one instead. This is often done something like:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/masi/.local --with-python=/home/masi/.local
```

For other setup.py-based extensions like MySQLdb you simply have to run the setup.py script with the correct version of Python:

```
/home/masi/.local/bin/python setup.py install
```

Comment: If you do not have setuptools in your system, please, see the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624671/unable-to-install-python-setuptools-from-source

Comment: Don't know about 2.6.X, but at least 2.7.9 and 3.x do not have a makefile before running the ./configure script. So maybe move "make clean" below the first call to configure?

Answer (score 40):

As of year 2020, [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) is the best choice for installing Python without sudo permission, supposing the system has necessary build dependencies.

```sh
# Install pyenv
$ curl https://pyenv.run | bash

# Follow the instruction to modify ~/.bashrc

# Install the latest Python from source code
$ pyenv install 3.8.3

# Check installed Python versions
$ pyenv versions

# Switch Python version
$ pyenv global 3.8.3

# Check where Python is actually installed
$ pyenv prefix
/home/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3

# Check the current Python version
$ python -V
Python 3.8.3
```

Comment: If after the first line one runs into `pyenv: command not found` please consider [my comments here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/issues/103#issue-744018427).

Comment: The most convenient approach by far.
One may ran into issues with read-only `TMPDIR` locations, export a new env. variable `export TMPDIR="/home/USERNAME/temp"`. Installing <3.8.0 may also result in errors caused by missing `_ctypes` which can be solved only via installing `libffi-dev` [issue31652](https://bugs.python.org/issue31652).

Comment: When running into the problem of @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄, there should be a directory ```~/.pyenv/```, just run ```~/.pyenv/bin/pyenv``` instead or add ```~/.pyenv/bin``` to your ```PATH```

Answer (score 4):

Extending bobince answer, there is an issue if you don't have the readline development package installed in your system, and you don't have root access.

When Python is compiled without readline, your arrow keys won't work in the interpreter. However, you can install the readline standalone package as follows: [Adding Readline Functionality Without Recompiling Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764730/adding-readline-functionality-without-recompiling-python)

On the other hand, if you prefer to compile python using a local installation of readline, here's how.

Before doing as bobince was telling, compile and install readline. These are the steps to do so:

- wget ftp://ftp.cwru.edu/pub/bash/readline-6.2.tar.gz
- tar -zxvf readline-6.2.tar.gz
- cd readline-6.2
- ./configure --with-prefix=$HOME/.local
- make
- make install

Then, add this line to your .bash_profile script:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/.local/lib
```

Last, but not least, execute the following command

```
export LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/.local"
```

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

You can't; not to `/usr`, anyway. Only superusers can write to those directories. Try installing Python to a path under your home directory instead.

Comment: What is "a path under my home directory"?

Comment: How can I install to a path under my home directory?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation on installing ( http://docs.python.org/using/unix.html ), particularly the part about paths and files.