# Adding Readline Functionality Without Recompiling Python

Tags: python, readline

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and refreshed my Python environment.  I installed Python 2.7 from source.  Unfortunately, I didn't notice that Setup.dist has the readline line commented out by default - by default, there is no readline support installed.  I'm now using the Python interpreter as a REPL enough that the constant ^[[A and ^[[D are very obnoxious.

Can I add readline support quickly, or do I have to actually recompile Python again?  It seems like the sort of thing where there *should* be a quick, sane way to do it, but I don't know such a way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a standalone [gnureadline package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gnureadline) available, you can install it using setuptools

```
$ easy_install readline
```

You might also consider using [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/) instead.

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: Oh hey, that worked.  My right pinkie, spared from infinite backspacing, thanks you.

Comment: You're a genius and saved me some incredible time. It's a shame your answer is not more upvoted than this haha.