# Is it possible to install another version of Python to Virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a shared account in a web-hosting that has Python 2.4 installed, but my code is not compatible with 2.4. Is it possible to install Python 2.6 directly to Virtualenv?

Note: I don´t have permission to install it in the shared server.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

**Here are the options for virtualenv**

```
$ virtualenv
You must provide a DEST_DIR
Usage: virtualenv [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit.
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit.
  -v, --verbose         Increase verbosity.
  -q, --quiet           Decrease verbosity.
  -p PYTHON_EXE, --python=PYTHON_EXE
                        The Python interpreter to use, e.g.,
                        --python=python2.5 will use the python2.5 interpreter
                        to create the new environment.  The default is the
                        interpreter that virtualenv was installed with
                        (/usr/bin/python)
  --clear               Clear out the non-root install and start from scratch
  --no-site-packages    Don't give access to the global site-packages dir to
                        the virtual environment
  --unzip-setuptools    Unzip Setuptools or Distribute when installing it
  --relocatable         Make an EXISTING virtualenv environment relocatable.
                        This fixes up scripts and makes all .pth files
                        relative
  --distribute          Use Distribute instead of Setuptools. Set environ
                        variable VIRTUALENV_USE_DISTRIBUTE to make it the
                        default
  --prompt==PROMPT      Provides an alternative prompt prefix for this
                        environment
```

**1) What you want to do is install python to a directory that you are able to write too.**

*You can follow the instructions [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622744/unable-to-install-python-without-sudo-access).*

**For Python 2.7.1**
[`Python source`](http://www.python.org/download/)

```
mkdir ~/src
mkdir ~/.localpython
cd ~/src
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.1/Python-2.7.1.tgz
tar -zxvf Python-2.7.1.tgz
cd Python-2.7.1

make clean
./configure --prefix=/home/${USER}/.localpython
make
make install
```

**2) Install virtualenv**
[`virtualenv source`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

```
cd ~/src
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.5.2.tar.gz#md5=fbcefbd8520bb64bc24a560c6019a73c
tar -zxvf virtualenv-1.5.2.tar.gz
cd virtualenv-1.5.2/
~/.localpython/bin/python setup.py install
```

**3) Create a virtualenv using your local python**
[`virtualenv docs`](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html)

```
mkdir /home/${USER}/virtualenvs
cd /home/${USER}/virtualenvs
~/.localpython/bin/virtualenv py2.7 --python=/home/${USER}/.localpython/bin/python2.7
```

**4) Activate the environment**

```
cd ~/virtualenvs/py2.7/bin
source ./activate
```

**5) Check**

```
(py2.7)$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Mar 31 2011, 15:31:37) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()

(py2.7)$ deactivate
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: brilliant writeup! two comments though: 1. i didn't have to do `make clean` before doing 
`./configure --prefix=/home/<user>/.localpython` in fact `make clean` returned error.  2. `virtualenv name -p=/python/path` didn't worked instead `virtualenv name -p /python/path` did worked. I assume it's down to virtualenv version. cheers!

Comment: I was jailshell'd out of gcc but was able to use ActiveState Python instead in step 1: http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/installnotes.html#aspackage_interactive

Comment: Here's a list of modules you need installed (on debian) to get this to work as close to a full install as possible: `curl gcc build-essential libncursesw5-dev libreadline5-dev libssl-dev libgdm-dev libbz2-dev libc6-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev`

Comment: If after doing this you delete all the stuff in .localpython, would the virtualenv still work?

Comment: Also, why are there 2 wget statements in the second line of step 2?  What is happening there?

Comment: `make` is not available to me on my shared server. how would I go around it? how do I install it if it absolutely necessary?

Comment: Nitpick: `source` is a bashism. The POSIX equivalent is `.`.

Comment: I find that doing this lot of basic modules are missing

Comment: So this is basically using the desired Python version to install virtualenv, rather than going other way round ?

Comment: In my case of Red Hat 6.3, I also need to  `yum install zlib-devel` and `yum install -y openssl-devel` to get `virtualenv` working. Without the former, `virtualenv` complains; without the latter, some "pip" and "HTTP" error was thrown. Also `virtualenv` is downloaded from here ` wget -O virtualenv-15.0.2.tar.gz https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/archive/15.0.2.tar.gz`

Comment: Note the current version of virtualenv is 15.2.0. I went to this site: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/15.2.0 and copied the link to "virtualenv-15.2.0.tar.gz (md5)" and pasted it in my wget command.

Comment: hi there, as year 2020, is this method still up to date? also why do I need to make and make install for installing another Python? ?

Answer (score 20):

Pre-requisites:

1. `sudo easy_install virtualenv`
2. `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper`

Installing virtualenv with Python2.6:

1. You could manually download, build and install another version of Python to `/usr/local` or another location.
2. If it's another location other than `/usr/local`, add it to your PATH.
3. Reload your shell to pick up the updated PATH.
4. From this point on, you should be able to call the following 2 python binaries from your shell `python2.5` and `python2.6`
5. Create a new instance of virtualenv with `python2.6`:

   `mkvirtualenv --python=python2.6 yournewenv`

Comment: i think the mkvirtualenv command only works when you have virtualenvwrapper installed.

Answer (score 5):

Full guide with [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

If pyenv is not installed then install it with [pyenv-installer](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer):

```
$ curl https://pyenv.run | bash
```

To use any custom python version, e.g. `3.5.6` use the following:

```
pyenv install 3.5.6
pyenv virtualenv 3.5.6 NAME_OF_YOUR_ENV
cd YOUR_PROJECT_PATH
pyenv local NAME_OF_YOUR_ENV
```

Answer (score 4):

Now a days, the easiest way I found to have a more updated version of Python is to install it via conda into a conda environment.

---

Install conda(you may need a virtualenv for this)

```
pip install conda
```

---

## Installing a new Python version inside a conda environent

I'm adding this answer here because no manual download is needed. `conda` will do that for you.

Now create an environment for the Python version you want. In this example I will use `3.5.2`, because it it the latest version at this time of writing (Aug 2016).

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5.2
```

Will create a environment for conda to install packages

---

To activate this environment(I'm assuming linux otherwise check the [conda docs](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html)):

```
source activate py35
```

---

Now install what you need either via pip or conda in the environemnt(conda has better binary package support).

```
conda install <package_name>
```

Answer (score 3):

The usual approach is to download the source and build and install locally (but not directly in virtualenv), and then create a new virtualenv using that local Python install.  On some systems, it may be possible to download and install a prebuilt python, rather than building from source.

Answer (score 3):

This procedure installs Python2.7 **anywhere and eliminates any absolute path references** within your `env` folder *(managed by virtualenv)*.  Even virtualenv isn't installed absolutely.

Thus, theoretically, you can drop the top level directory into a tarball, distribute, and run anything configured within the tarball on a machine that doesn't have Python *(or any dependencies)* installed.

Contact me with any questions.  This is just part of an ongoing, larger project I am engineering.  Now, for the drop...

1. Set up environment folders.

   ```
   $ mkdir env
   $ mkdir pyenv
   $ mkdir dep
   ```
2. Get Python-2.7.3, and virtualenv **without** any form of root OS installation.

   ```
   $ cd dep
   $ wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/Python-2.7.3.tgz
   $ wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py
   ```
3. Extract and install Python-2.7.3 into the `pyenv` dir. `make clean` is optional if you are doing this a 2nd, 3rd, Nth time...

   ```
   $ tar -xzvf Python-2.7.3.tgz
   $ cd Python-2.7.3
   $ make clean
   $ ./configure --prefix=/path/to/pyenv
   $ make && make install
   $ cd ../../
   $ ls
   dep    env    pyenv
   ```
4. Create your virtualenv

   ```
   $ dep/virtualenv.py --python=/path/to/pyenv/bin/python --verbose env
   ```
5. Fix the symlink to python2.7 within `env/include/`

   ```
   $ ls -l env/include/
   $ cd !$
   $ rm python2.7
   $ ln -s ../../pyenv/include/python2.7 python2.7
   $ cd ../../
   ```
6. Fix the remaining python symlinks in env.  You'll have to delete the symbolically linked directories and recreate them, as above.  Also, here's the syntax to force in-place symbolic link creation.

   ```
   $ ls -l env/lib/python2.7/
   $ cd !$
   $ ln -sf ../../../pyenv/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py UserDict.py
   [...repeat until all symbolic links are relative...]
   $ cd ../../../
   ```
7. Test

   ```
   $ python --version
   Python 2.7.1
   $ source env/bin/activate
   (env)
   $ python --version
   Python 2.7.3
   ```

Aloha.

Comment: Step 4 need pip module it seems. Tried with latest Python 2.7.9.

Comment: Tried going trough this, very incomplete answer with a lot of errors.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using virtualenvwrapper and don't want to modify $PATH, here's how:

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

$ mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3 env_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the question specifically describes installing 2.6, I would like to add some importants points to the excellent answers above in case someone comes across this. For the record, my case was that I was trying to install 2.7 on an ubuntu 10.04 box.

First, my motivation towards the methods described in all the answers here is that installing Python from [deadsnake's ppa's](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes) has been a total failure. So building a local Python is the way to go.

Having tried so, I thought relying to the default installation of pip (with `sudo apt-get install pip`) would be adequate. This unfortunately is wrong. It turned out that I was getting all shorts of nasty issues and eventually not being able to create a virtualenv.

Therefore, I highly recommend to **[install pip locally](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363300/how-to-install-pip-python-to-user-without-root-access)** with `wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py && python get-pip.py --user`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892071/pip-install-error-setuptools-command-not-found) related question gave me this hint.

Now if this doesn't work, make sure that [`libssl-dev`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318775/what-is-openssl-binaries-and-openssl-development-package) for Ubuntu or [`openssl-dev`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634895/importerror-while-installing-pip-in-virtualenv) for CentOS is installed. Install them with `apt-get` or `yum` and then re-build Python (no need to remove anything if already installed, do so on top). `get-pip` complains about that, you can check so by running `import ssl` on a py shell.

Last, don't forget to declare `.local/bin` and local python to path, check with `which pip` and `which python`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use pyenv.

There are a lot of different versions anaconda, jython, pypy and so on...

https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv

Installation as simple as `pyenv install 3.2.6`

```
pyenv install --list
Available versions:
  2.1.3
  2.2.3
  2.3.7
  2.4
  2.4.1
  2.4.2
  2.4.3
  2.4.4
  2.4.5
  2.4.6
  2.5
  2.5.1
  2.5.2
  2.5.3
  2.5.4
  2.5.5
  2.5.6
  2.6.6
```

...

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can install an isolated Python build (such as [ActivePython](http://activestate.com/activepython/downloads)) under your `$HOME` directory.

**This approach is the fastest**, and doesn't require you to compile Python yourself.

*(as a bonus, you also get to use ActiveState's [binary package manager](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/))*

Comment: Actually false as virtualenv is able to install another Python version.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found suitable answer, so here goes my take, which builds upon @toszter answer, but **does not use system Python** (and you may know, it is not always good idea to install setuptools and virtualenv at system level when dealing with many Python configurations):

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir python_ve
cd python_ve

MYROOT=`pwd`
mkdir env pyenv dep

cd ${MYROOT}/dep
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-15.2.tar.gz#md5=a9028a9794fc7ae02320d32e2d7e12ee
wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.9/Python-2.7.9.tar.xz
xz -d Python-2.7.9.tar.xz

cd ${MYROOT}/pyenv
tar xf ../dep/Python-2.7.9.tar
cd Python-2.7.9
./configure --prefix=${MYROOT}/pyenv && make -j 4 && make install

cd ${MYROOT}/pyenv

tar xzf ../dep/setuptools-15.2.tar.gz

cd ${MYROOT}

pyenv/bin/python dep/virtualenv.py --no-setuptools --python=${MYROOT}/pyenv/bin/python --verbose env
env/bin/python pyenv/setuptools-15.2/setup.py install
env/bin/easy_install pip

echo "virtualenv in ${MYROOT}/env"
```

The trick of breaking chicken-egg problem here is to make virtualenv without setuptools first, because it otherwise fails (pip can not be found). It may be possible to install pip / wheel directly, but somehow easy_install was the first thing which came to my mind. Also, the script can be improved by factoring out concrete versions.

NB. Using xz in the script.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Thank you DTing for awesome answer. It's pretty much perfect.

For those who are suffering from not having GCC access in shared hosting, Go for ActivePython instead of normal python like Scott Stafford mentioned. Here are the commands for that.

```
wget http://downloads.activestate.com/ActivePython/releases/2.7.13.2713/ActivePython-2.7.13.2713-linux-x86_64-glibc-2.3.6-401785.tar.gz

tar -zxvf ActivePython-2.7.13.2713-linux-x86_64-glibc-2.3.6-401785.tar.gz

cd ActivePython-2.7.13.2713-linux-x86_64-glibc-2.3.6-401785

./install.sh
```

It will ask you path to python directory. Enter

```
../../.localpython
```

Just replace above as Step 1 in DTing's answer and go ahead with Step 2 after that. Please note that ActivePython package URL may change with new release. You can always get new URL from here :  http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads

Based on URL you need to change the name of tar and cd command based on file received.

Answer (score 0):

virtualenv --python=".localpython/bin/python2.7" env