# Setup File for a Mac

Tags: python, installation

I know that Mac computers come preinstalled with an Apple port of Python. After installing the official Python from their website, how does one differentiate between these conflicting installations when running a setup script with `python setup.py install`?

Comment: You will have to specify the `python` interpreter you want to use more explicitly: `/path/to/python setup.py install`. Alternatively, use a `virtualenv` and [specify the interpreter with the `-p` flag](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1534210/3001761), then you can just use `python setup.py install` within that environment.

Comment: Where is the default path to the official Python? And is there an equivalent to Windows path environment variables to simplify such a path?

Comment: Have a look at e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5846167/3001761, there are numerous similar questions.