# Can't use python 3.6

Tags: python, pycharm, version

> I'm trying to work with python 3 and not python 2, I tried:

[image]

I clicked "Apply"

[image]

Here also, I clicked apply.

---

But when I check my version, it still in 2.7:

[image]

What should I do?

I'm using Mac OS X 10.11.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re using the terminal’s `python` rather than PyCharm’s. If you want to change your default Python you’ll need to update your `$PATH` variable. See this for more: [how to change default python version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846167/how-to-change-default-python-version)

If you just want to use PyCharm though, just right click on the file and click run.