# Switching from python 2.7 > 3.6

Tags: python

I initially used python 2.7 on my Mac, how can I now run 3.6 from the terminal? I have installed 3.6, but cannot find any instructions how to make 3.6 the default option.

Comment: Installed how? If you're using MacPorts or HomeBrew to run your installations, that tool will have its own mechanism for selecting defaults.

Comment: It'd also be a bad idea to make this the default, given the sharp incompatibilities between Python 2 and Python 3, and you could run the risk of deeply breaking something in your OS behind it.

Comment: anyway if both are installed usually to choose the 3.x just type python3

Comment: See http://www.janosgyerik.com/working-with-different-versions-of-python-on-osx-using-macports/ and related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846167/how-to-change-default-python-version

Comment: I was trying to run python program and I didn't realize I needed to use python3 instead of python to run python version 3.6

Comment: Thanks! Got it...

Comment: @SebastianŁącki you can also add `alias python="python3"` to your `.bash_profile` on MacOS so you can use `python` to call `python3` on the commandline

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the python version you want when running the program:

For Python 3.x

```
python3 filename.py
```

For Python 2.x:

```
python filename.py
```

You can also use an alias to specify the specific python version by typing this command:

```
alias python="python3"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the cmd line type `python3` where you would type `python` before.

To check which (and where) is currently the default version use `which python`

As others have pointed out, it's best to manage your installations through [something like pip, Homebrew, or Anaconda](http://www.pyladies.com/blog/Get-Your-Mac-Ready-for-Python-Programming/). It makes it much easier to keep track of packages and versions.