# Installing Local Version of Python

Tags: python, macos, command-line, installation

I'm trying to install my own version of Python that is independent of the system one on my Mac. Basically, I'm following this [Machine Learning Tutorial](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2016/06/introduction-deep-learning-python-caffe/). I'm in step 4.4 where I'm trying to run the command "python create_lmdb.py" in the command-line, but I get an error saying opencv module not found.

So, then I found the latest [openCV Tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/28/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-2-7/) for Sierra to install openCV properly. I am in step 2 and 3 where I've tried to edit the /.bash_profile with "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH". I've saved and opened the file to confirm that the file changed. I continued with the tutorial, but when I get to "which python" I find that Python is still the system version with the file path of /usr/bin/python rather than /usr/local/bin/python.

I've spent 3 days on this problem. I've searched around on here and tried various solutions. I've contacted Apple, but they of course couldn't help...or wouldn't. Googled like crazy. I've tried installing a different distribution of Python. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Python.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I recommend [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv); it's worked well for me.

Comment: or [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)?

Answer (score 0):

In essence, this is something that you don't want to change. For various reasons changing what your system believes to be "python" is not ideal. A more detailed anser can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846167/how-to-change-default-python-version), but for those that don't want to click through all you need to do is create a bash alias to the path you desire.

i.e. `alias py=/usr/bin/python3` or whatever the actual path is.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading through [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-macos) exhaustive guide for setting up Python (and optionally, virtual environments like other commenters have recommended) on OS X.