# Why is my Mac using python 2.7 when I have 3.8 already installed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal

I'm trying to install Selenium using pip. But when I go to my editor (pycharm CE running on 3.8) no such module exists. When I type python -version on terminal it comes up with python 2.7 with a deprecation warning. How to I change this? I'm pretty sure I have to change my path or something like that, but how? Any help is greatly appreciated.[image: python version]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change default python version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846167/how-to-change-default-python-version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because python2.7 is installed by default on Mac. Python3.8 is probably installed besides 2.7. Use `python3.8` command and `python3.8 -m pip install selenium` to install selenium for this specific python version. If pip is not installed for python3.8, [install it the official way](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

Don't replace system python, because that might break your OS.