# Python Libraries installing to Python 2.7 by default

Tags: python, libraries, pyperclip, modulenotfounderror

I recently shifted to a Macbook. I installed Python 3.8 and installed Pyperclip using `pip install pyperclip` in the terminal, which was successful. When I tried to import it in IDLE shell, I get the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'.

---

On looking around I found that pyperclip has been installed in-

```
/Users/aamodpant/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pyperclip
```

I did not install Python 2.7 but it must be required for macOS, so I don't want to delete it. How do I change the "default" version of Python for installing new libraries?

Comment: You might want to install with pip3

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall or upgrade `pyperclip` using `sudo`:

`pip3 install -U pyperclip`

Also, run your script using `python3` instead of just `python`:

`python3 script.py`

The best is to use `alias`, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5846177/8840245) describes changing default Python version in Mac can cause multiple issues.

```
alias python=python3
alias pip=pip3
```

> The answer you are probably looking for is You should not change this.

Otherwise, you may like to set Python 3 as default, there are many ways to do it. But do it with caution as the guides suggest below.

The official documentation: [Using Python on a Macintosh](https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html), some well described very good guides: [The right and wrong way to set Python 3 as default on a Mac](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac), [Installing Python 3 on Mac OS X](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/).

Comment: **NEVER** encourage the use of `sudo pip`. It is a security risk to use root privileges with pip to install Python. If someone puts a malicious project on PyPI and it's the installed with sudo, you give an attacker **root** access to your machine (see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/21056000/486919)

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
python3 -m pip install pyperclip
```

This will install the package for python3.