# python3 command on terminal runs python 3.8 not python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, macos-big-sur

Hi I cannot seem to understand why even though I just installed Python 3.9.5 (from here https://www.python.org/downloads/), the python3 command runs python 3.8.2 on the terminal, shown below.

This is my first time installing python on my Mac (macOS Big Sur).

```
MacBook-Air ~ % python --version
Python 2.7.16
MacBook-Air ~ % python3 --version
Python 3.8.2
```

How can I run what I actually installed, which is python3.9.5?
I appreciate your help.

Comment: Check out [How to change default Python version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5846167/3890632)

Comment: try doing `python3.9` instead of `python3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the current link and add a new symbolic link

```
unlink /usr/local/bin/python
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /usr/local/bin/python
```

---

If you also want to be able to run Python 3.9.5 by calling `python3` you can do so either as above or by updating your bash profile.

Inside `~/.bash_profile` simply add the following line:

```
alias python3='/usr/local/bin/python3.9'
```

and finally  reload it

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

You should now get

```
python3 --version
Python 3.9.5
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand why it run python 3.8 when I didn't even install this.. does it come embedded with python 3.9?

Comment: @bisuke I assume you already had Python 3.8 installed.

Comment: Thank you. For the first solution I got an error on terminal "unlink: /usr/bin/python: Operation not permitted". But I tried the second one - I edited my .zprofile instead and it worked. !