# Python version not updating

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently using Python 3.9 and slowly I am trying to convert to 3.10 (I expect to use both versions as some libraries are not available for 3.10). I have installed Python 3.10 and added it to path: `C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts` and placed it above python 3.9 which I have under: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts` but when I type `python --version` into Powershell, Python 3.9 is still showing up. I tried deleting 3.9 from path all together but Powershell was still displaying Python 3.9. Even in system variables, python 3.9 is placed below 3.10 but it has not produced any different result.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change default Python version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846167/how-to-change-default-python-version)

Comment: I will take a look, thank you

Comment: No, unfortunately, it doesn't solve my issue since that answer is focused on UNIX systems. I tried installing from Microsoft store but that didn't help in any way

Comment: Is it possible to add aliases to terminal? E.G. python39 and python310. So that i can type python310 - pip install ...?