# How to specify which python to use on macos

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, odoo

I had odoo installed which is a python based erp software.  At some point after that I installed python 3.0 which got installed alongside 2.7.18.  Now the run script python ./odoo.py fails because of that, or so I'm told by my it guy.  The error is:

```
(odoo-env) Marcios-MacBook-Pro:odoo mars$ python /odoo.pyc
dyld[2773]: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/mars/odoo-env/bin/python2.7
  Reason: tried: '/Users/mars/odoo-env/bin/../.Python' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/.Python' (no such file), '/usr/lib/.Python' (no such file)
Abort trap: 6
```

[image: Error in terminal]

I'm told I need to specify which python version to use.  Does anyone know where to do that?

Comment: Could [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846167/how-to-change-default-python-version) probably help you?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: I followed the instructions from that first answer and was able to link python 2.7 and 3.x but i still cant run my odoo python script.  I get the exact same error