# Pip installs packages in the wrong directory

Tags: python, pip, python-module, python-packaging, pythonpath

So I want to install the opencv-python package. I typed in pip install opencv-python and got this:

```
Collecting opencv-python
  Downloading opencv_python-4.7.0.72-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (38.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 38.2/38.2 MB 3.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.0 in c:\users\leo westerburg burr\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.24.2)
Installing collected packages: opencv-python
Successfully installed opencv-python-4.7.0.72
```

When I try and import the package (on IDLE) I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

This is the same for all the packages I have installed recently, like numpy. The thing is when I type `sys.path` into the IDLE I get

```
C:\Users\Leo Westerburg Burr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\idlelib
C:\Users\Leo Westerburg Burr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python311.zip
C:\Users\Leo Westerburg Burr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\DLLs
C:\Users\Leo Westerburg Burr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib
C:\Users\Leo Westerburg Burr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311
C:\Users\Leo Westerburg Burr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages
```

Which are all in the `AppData/Local/Programs` directory, however the packages are stored in `appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\...` as you can see when I installed opencv-python - which I find weird; why are they installed there and not in `programs\python` ?

I have tried reinstalling pip, and also downloading a newer version of python. What is weird is that I have Python311 and Python38 in my Python folder, but this weird folder that has the packages is python39?

So my question is: how do I get pip to install packages in `Programs\Python\Python311\...`, rather than `Packages\...` ?

Do I have to add something to my PATH?

Comment: Try `python -m pip install ...`

Comment: @C.Nivs Thank you, this worked. Do you know what the problem was?

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `python -m pip install`. Why? `pip` is an executable that may or may not share an installation directory with your standard `python`. You can verify this by comparing:

```bash
pip -V

python -m pip -V
```

The latter command, `python -m pip install` ensures that `pip` is the one linked to the `python` command you run for IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have both python3.9 and 3.11 installed. When just typing in `pip install ...` you probably install your package in python 3.9 whereas you run python 3.11 in IDLE.

Try `python -V` in your command prompt, it will probably answer python3.11

Comment: It returns `Python 3.9.13`.  How do I change this to 3.11?

Comment: you can check the answer to a similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846167/how-to-change-default-python-version