# Issue in getting Python location in macbook

Tags: python, macos

I had 3.11 already and installed 3.10 now.

```
ls
3.10    3.11    Current
```

```
pwd
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin
```

```
ls
2to3            pip3.10         python3-intel64
2to3-3.10       pydoc3          python3.10
idle3           pydoc3.10       python3.10-config
idle3.10        python3         python3.10-intel64
pip3            python3-config
```

```
python3 --version
Python 3.11.4
```

Why is it showing as 3.11.4 when the directory I am in is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin`?

Comment: If you want to explicitly use the executable from the current directory: `./python3`.

Comment: Also you might want to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846167/how-to-change-default-python-version

Comment: *echo $PATH* will give you a clue

Answer (score 0):

because of the path search order

```
export PATH=/dir1:/dir2:$PATH
```

so when you type python3, it found the 3.11 first

you can use

```
./python3 --version
```

which will output 3.10