# Can't import a builtin module python3.12

Tags: python, linux, xfce

I can't import 'requests' and not because it's not installed but because in its import tree there is an unknown module 'six.moves' here is the code

```
admin-hox@Admin-PC:~/Documents/Projects/python/random$ python3.12
Python 3.12.0 (main, Oct  2 2023, 15:05:04) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from six.moves.http_client import IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves'
>>>
```

But it works on python3

```
admin-hox@Admin-PC:~/Documents/Projects/python/random$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, May 26 2023, 14:05:08) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>>
```

Comment: What are your packages in the Python 3.12 env? In particular, your urllib3 version?

Comment: According to ```pip list``` the version of urllib3 is 1.25.8

urllib3               1.25.8

Comment: I updated urllib3 to 2.0.7 and it still doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

In your "working" example, the python version is `3.8.10`, whereas in your first example you're using `3.12.0`. There are a few ways to fix this (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846167/how-to-change-default-python-version) and [the pyenv project](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)). The quick way to fix this would be to symlink `python3` to your installation of `python3.12`.

You can check where `python3` points to by running `readlink -f $(which python3)`, then run `ln -s $(which python3) $(which python3.12)` to create the link to the newer installation.