# HOWTO: Install python2.x within virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python - It is possible to install another version of Python to Virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506110/python-it-is-possible-to-install-another-version-of-python-to-virtualenv)

Within my (virtualenv activated) env folder, it appears as though the python2.7 folder has symlinks to **absolute paths** for my system python installation.

This is not ideal.

*Even when I install from a local path, and use virtualenv to set and environment in a folder `env`, the paths to Python are absolute, and a dependency on the OS environment is established.  I want to rid this dependency and make the python interpreter, as well as all software relying upon it, completely independent.*

Let's imagine that I want python2.6 to be included IN the env tree as a STAND-ALONE installation without symlinks to my system folders.

How does one accomplish this feat of extraordinary non-linkage?

```
$ > pwd 
/Users/foo/development/v1/bar/env
(env)
$ > ls -l lib/python2.7/
total 920
lrwxr-xr-x  1 foo  staff     82 Oct 15 16:48 UserDict.py -> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py
...
lrwxr-xr-x  1 foo  staff     85 Oct 15 16:48 _weakrefset.py -> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
```

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:  Moreover, it will be most ideal to have the virtualenv (including the local python install) relocatable.

Comment: Installing a Python interpreter from scratch probably simply isn't in the scope of `virtualenv`. Install a Python yourself into the env folder and then tell `virtualenv` to use that installation, making it relocatable as needed.

Comment: @Insidi0us - I couldn't find that dupe... thank you.

Comment: Just install another Python, like an OS X Python installer from python.org, and use it instead of the Apple-supplied system Python to install new instances of Distribute and/or pip and virtualenv, if you really need to use it.  But it's unlikely that you really need to or should build Python from source.  It's a bit tricky to get right, especially on OS X.  Another option is to install everything you need from a 3rd-party package manager, like MacPorts.

Comment: @millimoose - Good idea, however, when I tried this, virtualenv borks with "shutil.Error: `/Users/foo/development/env/bin/python` and `env/bin/python` are the same file"

Comment: @toszter Don't install Python and the virtualenv into the same directory. Put at least one of them (preferrably Python, not the virtualenv) into a separate subdirectory under `env`, say `env/sdk`

Comment: @millimoose - Indeed, I installed python to pyenv/ and made all python symlinks within env/ relative.  Running `virtualenv --relocatable env` did not fix the relative symlinks.  Tested and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE: Please ALSO refer to [Is it possible to install another version of Python to Virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506110/python-it-is-possible-to-install-another-version-of-python-to-virtualenv)**

Big thanks to @millimoose, et al.

Here's what I ended up doing, very specifically.  I will update if I encounter problems in the future.

1. Set up environment folders.

   ```
   $ mkdir env
   $ mkdir pyenv
   $ mkdir dep
   ```
2. Get Python-2.7.3, and virtualenv **without** any form of root OS installation.

   ```
   $ cd dep
   $ wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/Python-2.7.3.tgz
   $ wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py
   ```
3. Extract and install Python-2.7.3 into the `pyenv` dir. `make clean` is optional if you are doing this a 2nd, 3rd, Nth time...

   ```
   $ tar -xzvf Python-2.7.3.tgz
   $ cd Python-2.7.3
   $ make clean
   $ ./configure --prefix=/path/to/pyenv
   $ make && make install
   $ cd ../../
   $ ls
   dep    env    pyenv
   ```
4. Create your virtualenv

   ```
   $ dep/virtualenv.py --python=/path/to/pyenv/bin/python --verbose env
   ```
5. Fix the symlink to python2.7 within `env/include/`

   ```
   $ ls -l env/include/
   $ cd !$
   $ rm python2.7
   $ ln -s ../../pyenv/include/python2.7 python2.7
   $ cd ../../
   ```
6. Fix the remaining python symlinks in env.  You'll have to delete the symbolically linked directories and recreate them, as above.  Also, here's the syntax to force in-place symbolic link creation.

   ```
   $ ls -l env/lib/python2.7/
   $ cd !$
   $ ln -sf ../../../pyenv/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py UserDict.py
   [...repeat until all symbolic links are relative...]
   $ cd ../../../
   ```
7. Test

   ```
   $ python --version
   Python 2.7.1
   $ source env/bin/activate
   (env)
   $ python --version
   Python 2.7.3
   ```

Aloha.

Comment: This is one of the best self-answers I've seen in a while.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [pythonbrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew) to get an isolated Python installation.
2. Use that Python installation to initiate your virtual environment.
3. Make the virtual environment [relocatable](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#making-environments-relocatable).

Comment: Thank you, but in this case, the python install now has a dependency on pythonbrew, and I want to transport the python source without **any** dependencies.

Comment: You don't need pythonbrew to be transported, you just need it to setup your portable environment.