# uwsgi - not using python2.7.3 from virtualenv, but using 2.6 from venv even though 2.6 installed only globally

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

My system(ubuntu) has python 2.6.5  version  (globally installed in /usr/bin/).
I want to use python 2.7.3 .
For this, I tried creating a virtualenv using this answer [Is it possible to install another version of Python to Virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506110/python-it-is-possible-to-install-another-version-of-python-to-virtualenv) (didnt do any simlinking from answers)  . I succeeded in this and when I activated env and used 'python manage.py shell' it worked great .

Problem is : 
 We use uwsgi for running server . Till now, we are directly using the system wide python(2.6.5) . As I have installed everything newly in a virtualenv, I added the option

```
'-H /path/to/virtualenv'
```

while running the uwsgi server.

I got the error "no module named 'os' " while executing line "import os"  . (Found error from error logs)

So,  I added import sys; print sys.path commands before the command 'import os' . Then,
when it printed the path, it had something like :

```
 /home/name/venv/bin/python/lib/python2.6/  #(one of the items in the array sys.path)
```

But, when I looked at my venv folder, there is nothing like python2.6 in the 'lib' folder. 
,My lib folder of venv contains only 'python2.7' .

My requirement is, uwsgi should use python 2.7(of venv) , not 2.6 (global).

Also, in my sh file, I used command 'which python' which showed me that it is using global version. So, I have to tell the shell file first to use python from the virtualenv, not the default global one. I tried 'source /path/to/activate' but said command not found.

Comment: Did you install uwsgi in the virtualenv ?

Comment: Try to run the one that you installed in the virtualenv, this works for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. **Activate virtualenv**,
2. **Install uwsgi**: `pip install uwsgi`
3. **Run uwsgi** from the virtualenv.

Comment: Just in case, _running_ uwsgi doesn't require the virtualenv to be activated, this is only needed first time to install it.