# Pip install error. Setuptools.command not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pymongo

I'm using a clean instance of Ubuntu server and would like to install some python packages in my virtualenv.

I receive the following output from the command 'pip install -r requirements.txt'

```
Downloading/unpacking pymongo==2.5.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Downloading pymongo-2.5.2.tar.gz (303kB): 303kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pymongo
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named setuptools.command
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>

ImportError: No module named setuptools.command

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/redacted/env/build/pymongo
Storing complete log in /home/redacted/.pip/pip.log
```

Any Idea what's going on?

python version 2.7.3

pip version pip 1.4 from /home/redacted/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try installing:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

if this doesn't work try:

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

**Edit:** If you have several (possible conflicting) python installations or environments, the following commands can be useful to debug which executables are being used:

```
which python
which pip
which easy_install
```

They should "match". It can happen for example that you have pip installing packages for an EPD or global distribution while the current python that is being used corresponds to a local environment (or something different), in which case it might not be able to see the installed packages.

Comment: I tried that, both globally as you suggested and with 'pip install setuptools' in my virutalenv. Still no luck.

Comment: @Sam, what about now?

Comment: Still does not work, though now I have pip installed globally.

Comment: @Sam, did you run easy_install and python inside the environment?

Comment: Can you explain to me why that worked when used inside the virtual environment?

Comment: If you run `which python` and `which easy_install` you should see that the corresponding env's executable are being used.

Comment: **DON'T USE THE LINK** python-distribute will redirect you into spam website

Answer (score 20):

had the same problem, solved it with

```
pip install -U setuptools
```

Comment: This actually solved the problem when nothing else did. Seems to need a more updated setuptools than the ones that ship with either the OS or even a pyenv install. Weird.

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating @elyase's Answer.
First check for which python version you want to install setuptools.
Normally both python versions comes default with debian or any linux distro.
So, as per your requirement install setup tools using apt package manager

For python 2.x

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

For python 3.x

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me.  I can run these commands but then if I try to invoke python-setuptools I get "python-setuptools: command not found"

Answer (score 1):

These instructions solved the problem for me:

first enter these commands

```sh
    pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install --upgrade wheel
    pip install setuptools
```

and then try to install the package that requires `setuptools`.