# ImportError: No module named setuptools.command on Mac OS X within virtualenv

Tags: python, django, macos, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Trying to install a Python pip package (Django Rest Framework docs, [`drfdocs`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/drfdocs/)) on Mac OSX within a virtualenv:

Here are the relevant versions of pip, python, easy_install:

```
$ virtualenv --version
1.11.4

$ mkvirtualenv test
New python executable in test/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.

(test)$ python --version; which python
Python 2.7.10
/Users/me/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python

(test)$ pip --version; which pip
pip 1.5.4 from /Users/me/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
/Users/me/.virtualenvs/test/bin/pip

(test)$ easy_install --version; which easy_install
setuptools 2.2
/Users/me/.virtualenvs/test/bin/easy_install

(test)$ python -c "import setuptools.command; print setuptools.command"
<module 'setuptools.command' from '/Users/me/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/__init__.pyc'>
```

And here's the error:

```
$ pip install drfdocs
Downloading/unpacking drfdocs
  Downloading drfdocs-0.0.11.tar.gz (771kB): 771kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/Users/me/.virtualenvs/test/build/drfdocs/setup.py) egg_info for package drfdocs
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named setuptools.command
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>

ImportError: No module named setuptools.command

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /Users/me/.virtualenvs/test/build/drfdocs
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/me/.pip/pip.log
```

I tried a variety of fixes from other Stack Overflow answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892071/pip-install-error-setuptools-command-not-found), but none worked.

```
$ pip install -U setuptools
```

did not help either.

---

**EDIT**: As requested:

```
(test)$ python -c "import setuptools; print setuptools.__file__; print setuptools.__version__"
/Users/me/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.pyc
2.2
```

---

**EDIT #2**: I tried `pip install pip --upgrade` so now I'm on `pip==8.1.2`.

Now when I try to install I get a slightly different error:

```
(test)$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import setuptools
>>> exit()
(test)$ pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /Users/me/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
(test)$ pip install drfdocs
Collecting drfdocs
  Using cached drfdocs-0.0.11.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named setuptools

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/kc/00fkv5q91vz815b2jycc8cv40000gn/T/pip-build-olnkAD/drfdocs/
```

Still doesn't make sense why this is happening though.

Comment: when you `pip freeze` , can you see setuptools in the outcome?

Comment: What is the output of this snippet from a Python interactive shell? `import setuptools; setuptools.__file__; setuptools.__version__`

Comment: @Justin: no, it does not. I see only "wsgiref==0.1.2" for my "test" virtualenv.

Comment: @lollercoaster Have you tried the documentation? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools there is a specific section for python 2.7

Comment: @JustinM.Ucar: I think you're missing the issue. The point is that `pip` should "just work" for this mind-numbingly simple sort of task/install. There must be something wrong with my setup, but I'm not quite sure what it is.

Comment: @lollercoaster i just created a virtualenv on my machine and it works OOB. It is already installed however it is not listed in `pip freeze`. The only difference i see here is the version of virtualenv. I haver it at version 15.0.1.
May be your vistualenv needs upgrading?

Comment: @JustinM.Ucar: Running `(test)$ pip install virtualenv --upgrade; pip install drfdocs` had the same result, sadly.

Comment: @lollercoaster With all the same versions, I can't replicate the error, alas.  I do get that error if I try to use the setuptools included with Mac OSX, however.  Perhaps pip is not inside the virtualenv?

Comment: @LexScarisbrick: hmm, that would make a lot of sense. However `which pip` returns `/Users/me/.virtualenvs/test/bin/pip` and it doesn't seem like it's a symlink to anything.

Comment: Have you tried: pip install --upgrade setuptools

Comment: @HendriTobing: yes. And uninstalling and reinstalling `setuptools` as well.

Comment: @lollercoaster Can you try creating your virtualenv as not hidden. Just to see if it makes any difference. `/Users/me/virtualenvs/test/` instead of `/Users/me/.virtualenvs/test/`

Comment: Assuming you are using bash...  Have you checked whether it has cached pip?  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables

Comment: @lollercoaster Do you use the system default python? If so I recommend installing a real one with brew and then create a virualenv from that.

Comment: Homebrew installs Setuptools and pip for you. You may try to uninstall and reinstall your python distribution. Look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22800774/1945707)

Comment: Are you running on El Capitan? There are a number of problems installing packages when using the system-installed copy of Python on El Capitan. You may be better off installing your own copy of Python. See this answer for more details: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/223163/143849

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in package. See [issue #120](https://github.com/ekonstantinidis/django-rest-framework-docs/issues/120)

Wait for [v0.1.0](https://github.com/ekonstantinidis/django-rest-framework-docs/milestone/3) or download [package from PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/packages/e5/9e/3a9aa6908ad7bd95b46f7fe05256681f4101de9a7769b6928159a986ef61/drfdocs-0.0.11.tar.gz), remove `site` directory from this package, install patched package.