# create virtual environment for python 2.7

Tags: python, django, macos, python-2.7

I want to install django, but my system which it's os is mac has python 2.6 which can't support django. so I installed python 2.7 but at that time when I typed python in terminal it response the version is 2.6 after searching I change it to python 2.7 where both of them are still on my computer, when I want to install django it still install it for 2.6 so I decide to install virtual environment but when I create a new environment using "virtualenv venv" it produce environment with python version 2.6! I really confused what should I do to create virtual environment with python 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can edit the PATH in ~/.bash_profile to make sure that path for python 2.7 is in front of 2.6 version.

It is a good/common practice to not touch the system python on MAC OS and install a latest version using homebrew. After you installed brew you can install python by:

```
brew install python
```

Homebrew will take care of the PATH. After that you will be able to install packages and control virtual environments with your 2.7 installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your python interpreter as a prefix to virtualenv_install

Refer to this post: [Is it possible to install another version of Python to Virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506110/it-is-possible-to-install-another-version-of-python-to-virtualenv)

What I mean to say is create a new virtual env with the correct python interpreter by specifying it as such:

```
mkdir virtualenvs
cd virtualenvs
~/.localpython/bin/virtualenv py2.7 --python=/home/<user>/.localpython/bin/python2.7
```

(See the stackoverflow post I mentioned)

Comment: can you explain more what is "/opt/python-2.7.5/bin/python setup.py" and "/apps/hotspot/venv/virtualenv_install"