# How can I remove a version of Python in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, python-3.3

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 which comes with Python 2.7. I have installed Python 3.3, so now I have both versions. For example, if I type python in the terminal I get version 2.7 and if I type python3.3 I get that version.

I don't see why I would need 2 versions (?) so how do I uninstall Python 2.7? And if I do so, will the "python" command then point to Python 3.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**VERY IMPORTANT EDIT**

Removing an older version of python may be very dangerous and can cause trouble in your whole system! For your case instead of removing the older python you can simply use an alias in your terminal, so that when you type python it opens python3.3;

Here is the procedure, add this line:

```
alias python=python3
```

Into`~/.bash_aliases`  or: `~/.bashrc`

---

Btw I guess If you ask this question in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) you may have a quicker/better response!

Answer (score 0):

You should **never** remove the builtin Python in your Ubuntu distribution. Bad things will happen if you do.

It is highly recommended to use virtualenv to install other Python environments.

Here's a good Stackoverflow question that demonstrates how:

- [Is it possible to install another version of Python to Virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506110/it-is-possible-to-install-another-version-of-python-to-virtualenv)