# How does one distinguish between 32 and 64 bit python?

Tags: python, 64-bit, 32-bit

I've come to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21789519/7395911) regarding how to install 32 bit Python on Linux and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3117626/7395911) on Windows. After reading I decided to find out which python I had, if it was 32 or 64 bits.

I've tried the following, but the difference in the results bugged me:

**Python 2.7**

```py
import sys
sys.getsizeof(int(1))
>>> 24
```

**Python 3.6**

```py
import sys
sys.getsizeof(int(1))
>>> 28
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10365639/7395911) helped me understand it, but I don't know a proper way to find out if I have 32 or 64 bit python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine if my python shell is executing in 32bit or 64bit mode on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os)

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842544/how-do-i-detect-if-python-is-running-as-a-64-bit-application

Comment: @AMC The last one has some problems that states the it is not [reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107905/which-command-to-use-for-checking-whether-python-is-64bit-or-32bit/12057504#comment16107570_12057504)

Comment: Yes, although the other answer to that post looks alright.

Comment: @AMC Yes, thanks for that! The first one catches most problems, also mentions some caveats. I could wonder about python <2.6 versions but that would be another question.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck :)