# How do I install a previous version of Python into a virtualenv?

Tags: python

I had Python3 installed globally, then I made a virtualenv. Now I want to change the python version inside to Python2.7. Trying to install Python2.7 gives me only the option of installing to my hard disk. How can I specify the version in my virtualenv?

Comment: virtualenv provides a way of running an *existing* version of python within a clean room.  So you will need to install python 2.7 somewhere before using virtualenv on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First and foremost, it most certainly is. If we take a look at `virtualenv --help`, we will see that we have the option to specify the `python` executable using the `-p` flag. However, your problem is slightly different since you already have `python3` linked to your `python` executable. In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506110/is-it-possible-to-install-another-version-of-python-to-virtualenv) is is talked about. However, it isn't a very good anwer since it involves making, and then symlinking a new python installation.

Instead, it is better to use a python version manage live `pyenv` or `pythonz`. I myself prefer `pyenv`. If you are on a *nix machine, then simply follow the instructions [outlined here](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-installer).

Once this installation is complete, you should see that you get a few instructions towards the end of the installation.

```
# Load pyenv automatically by adding
# the following to ~/.zshrc:

export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Simply at this to the end of your .bashrc or .zshrc. If you're using windows, then this process will be a lot harder. There is a [`pip` installer](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-installer#pypi-way). However, please note that it is not fully stable yet.

Once all of this is done, all you need to do is install the version of python that you want.

```
pyenv install 2.7.10
```

Once this is done, run `pyenv rehash`, then run `pyenv global <version you installed>` (which maybe different from 2.7.10).

Now you can go ahead just create a virtual environment with `virtualenv`, and it should have the version of python you want.

Comment: Alright. This is helpful, but it seems more complicated than just installing Python2.7 and using the -p. I'll try that first.

Comment: If you use the `venv` module, `pyenv install` will give you the path to the Python you installed. Just call this Python to create your virtual environment: `<path_to_pyenv_installed_python>/python -m venv <path_to_virtual_environment>`