# How to run a previous version of Python using virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

My native python installation is currently 3.10.2, however there is a program I need to use that is only compatible with 2.7-3.8. Rather than deleting my native installation and installing an outdated version, I'm trying to run Python 3.8 in virtualenv, but even when I set `pyenv global 3.8.13`, the python version in my virtualenv is still 3.10.2.

Demonstration:

set global version

```
pyenv global 3.8.13
```

verify

```
pyenv global
```

returns

```
3.8.13
```

make virtual environment

```
pyenv virtualenv test 
pyenv activate test
python --version
```

returns

```
Python 3.10.2
```

Following the instructions on this post [How do I install a previous version of Python into a virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918846/how-do-i-install-a-previous-version-of-python-into-a-virtualenv), I have both pyenv and virtualenv installed, as well as python 3.8 in the `$HOME/.pyenv/versions` folder. Any idea why this version isn't being used in the virtual environments that I create?

output of `pyenv versions`

```
system
* 3.8.13 (set by $HOME/.pyenv/version)
```

Let me know if I can provide more detail.

Comment: In general, avoid setting a global Python. You don't want it messing somewhere is shouldn't.

Comment: Solved using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506110/is-it-possible-to-install-another-version-of-python-to-virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```sh
pyenv virtualenv 3.8.13 test
```

Then use either of the following:

```sh
cd /path/to/project
pyenv local 3.8.13/envs/test
```

```sh
pyenv activate 3.8.13/envs/test
```

Source: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv#using-pyenv-virtualenv-with-pyenv

Comment: No, was still 3.10.2 in the environment

Comment: Try to restart your terminal and run `pyenv rehash`...

Comment: Same problem :/

restarted terminal then
`pyenv rehash`, 
`pyenv activate test_2`,
`python --version`
returns `3.10.2`

Comment: What does `pyenv which python` return?

Comment: `$HOME/.pyenv/versions/test_2/bin/python`

Comment: Additionally, you could try this: `pyenv exec python --version`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243694/discussion-between-eccentricorange-and-lcleary).

Comment: fyi, still haven't figured this out