# Manually install pip into virutalenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to create a virtualenv in which I will run an older version of Django (1.4.2) and a specific version of Python (2.7.8) on OSX El Capitan.  Here are the steps I went through:

I downloaded and compiled Python 2.7.8 using this workflow:
[Is it possible to install another version of Python to Virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506110/is-it-possible-to-install-another-version-of-python-to-virtualenv)

When I try to create a new virtualenv with --python flag pointed to my newly compiled Python2.7.8, I get an error message that looks like this:

```
  Complete output from command /Users/luka/xxx/virtu...y2_7_8/bin/python2.7 -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-13.1.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-13.1.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-13.1.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-13.1.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 35, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-13.1.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-13.1.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 31, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler
```

If I rerun the same command with --no-setuptools flag, everything works properly, I get access to the Python version I need, but I don't have pip and setuptools in the site-package directory, which is a problem because now I can't install a specific version of Django inside my virtualenv.  Can I simply copy existing system-wide pip installation into my virtualenv or install pip in some other way inside of it?

Thanks!
Luka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just install `pip` in the new virtualenv [using the `get-pip.py` script](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#install-pip):

1. Download `get-pip.py`, e.g. using wget or curl
2. Run it with the virtualenv's python, i.e. activate the virtualenv and then run `python get-pip.py`