# Running fabric script throws ImportError: No module named fabric.main

Tags: python, python-2.7, redhat, fabric, importerror

I am on Redhat, and when I run any fabric scripts I see the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/fab", line 8, in
>   
>       from fabric.main import main ImportError: No module named fabric.main

The file /usr/bin/fab is configured to use python 2.7 (/usr/local/bin/python):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python     
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- import re import sys

from fabric.main import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

The result is the same even if I just call fab.
Not sure what else I should be configuring. I have not set up a `virtualenv` for fab. If I must, I will do so.

I installed python 2.7, and then I installed fab as follows:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo /usr/local/bin/python get-pip.py
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install fab
```

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/pip install fab` probably installed the fabric module executable in `/usr/local/bin/fab` and not `/usr/bin`. Not sure where the `/usr/bin/fab` came from in your situation.

Comment: Thank you, however it seems I do not have a /usr/local/bin/fab either ..

Comment: However, this did help me find the resolution to my problem (see my answer below) -- so thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think I actually helped any, but glad you figured out a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

1. Install Python 2.7 in a virtualenv (`~/virtualenvs/py2.7`) by following the top-rated answer from [Is it possible to install another version of Python to Virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506110/is-it-possible-to-install-another-version-of-python-to-virtualenv) by DTing
2. Install pip in `~/virtualenvs/py2.7/bin/`:

   `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
    sudo ~/virtualenvs/py2.7/bin/python2.7 get-pip.py`
3. Install fab in `~/virtualenvs/py2.7/bin`:

   `sudo ~/virtualenvs/py2.7/bin/pip install fab`
4. For some reason, I still did not have the fab file under `~/virtualenvs/py2.7/bin`, so I just copied the original `/usr/bin/fab` that was giving me issues to `~/virtualenvs/py2.7/bin/` and edited it to point to the virtualenv python2.7 (`~/virtualenvs/py2.7/bin/python2.7`)

Running `~/virtualenvs/py2.7/bin/fab` worked, and gave me the following (welcome) error:

> Fatal error: Couldn't find any fabfiles!
>
> Remember that -f can be used to specify fabfile path, and use -h for
>   help.
>
> Aborting.

I am content for now -- since fab seems to work. But if anyone has ideas why the actual fab file was not created in the `~/virtualenvs/py2.7/bin/` directory, I am all ears. Thank you!