# How to switch python version from 3.6.0 to 3.6.7 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I would am currently using python version 3.6.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 and need to use python version >= 3.6.1 to use PySlice_Unpack.

I have tried installing using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

The output from these commands is:

```
python3.6 is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04).
```

So it seems like I already have python 3.6.7 installed. However when I run the commands python -V, python3 -V, or python3.6 -V the output is

```
Python 3.6.0 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

In /usr/bin/ I have config files for python2.7, python3.6, python3.6m, python3, and python3m. I've looked at the python3.6 and python3 config files and they both have VERSION="3.6". How can I switch to using python version 3.6.7 instead of 3.6.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a different version of Python (or other versions of python packages than those included in the version of Ubuntu you are using), then you might want to try using [VirtualEnv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), like explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5507373/483566