# How to install python3 without admin rights on Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, installation

I want to install python3 on a computer that I do not have admin rights. Are there any ways to go around ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try python virtual environments, which is probably good practice even if you have admin rights. Here is a good guide to python virtual environments: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: But you need to get *some* version of Python installed to use `virtualenv` at all, surely?

Comment: Indeed you need to install in you home directory. The key is the `--prefix` argument during the configuration. See a SO post about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622744/unable-to-install-python-without-sudo-access

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading the .zip from the python website https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-371/ under files.

Although you won't find IDLE as a part of this python by default. You can use any other IDE or just cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Download msi file for particular version and mention the target directory name and run below command in Download folder(where msi placed)

msiexec /a python-2.7.10.msi /qb TARGETDIR=D:\python27

inside D:\python27  we got python path and application